# HAProxy: API on the same subdomain as frontend

Tags: haproxy

I've got such a configuration in my `haproxy.cfg` file:

```
    acl is_api url_beg -i /api
    acl is_frontend hdr(host) -i subdomain.mydomain.com

    use_backend api if is_api
    use_backend nginx-frontend if is_frontend
```

My goal:

Hitting `subdomain.mydomain.com` will serve files using `nginx` unless the `path` starts with `/api` (`subdomain.mydomain.com/api/*`) - then it should use my `api` backend.

Now, using the current configuration, when I restart `haproxy` service, there are two scenarios:

1. I go to `subdomain.mydomain.com` - it's serving `nginx-frontend` - great. Then I go to `subdomain.mydomain.com/api` - 404 (`nginx` was used).
2. I go to `subdomain.mydomain.com/api` it's serving `api` - great. Then I go to `subdomain.mydomain.com` - 404 (the `api` backend was used).

So depending on the order of my first visit on either page, all the requests to my subdomain are assigned to either backend...

I'm a total newbie, I'm sorry if that's a stupid question.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured out a way... but in `nginx` configuration (`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`):

```
server {
    listen 8080 default_server;
    listen [::]:8080 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name subdomain.mydomain.com;
    location /api {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4001;
    }

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

and in `haproxy.cfg` file:

```
backend nginx
    server nginx-1 127.0.0.1:8080 check

frontend all
    bind *:80
    mode http

    acl is_frontend hdr(host) -i subdomain.mydomain.com
    use_backend nginx if is_frontend

    # other frontends...
```

If somebody could comment on if it's a good approach, I'd be grateful!

Answer (score 0):

It gives 404 because of `url_beg`. This uses the full URL and not the trailing part after the domain i.e. it gets `"http..."` in `http://subdomain.mydomain.com/api`

> **url_beg** 
>   Returns true when the URL begins with one of the strings. This can be used to
>   check whether a URL begins with a slash or with a protocol scheme.

Use `path_beg` instead.

```
frontend fe
  ...
  acl is_api path_beg -i /api
  acl is_frontend hdr(host) -i subdomain.mydomain.com

  use_backend api if is_api
  use_backend nginx-frontend if is_frontend !is_api
```